# design consideration of multi currency hotel reservation system

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

I am building a hotel reservation website in asp.net 3.5.this website stores the hotel details and room rates of hotels across the world.

In hotels admin module,webmaster and hotel admin will enter the room rates and other prices in their native currency.and in the front end the stored prices should be converted to users respective currency.

i am confused in the designing of system.how to store the currency values.
i am using sql server as database.

Comment: The biggest problem with currency exchange rates is that they are constantly changing. You will have to subscribe to some sort of feed service.

Comment: What are you using for data storage? SQL Server? Knowing this will help us give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currency rates (can) fluctuate significantly on a very short-term basis; you should be accessing a service which will give you the most up-to-date currency exchange rate.  [This](http://www.xmethods.net/ve2/ViewListing.po?serviceid=5) 
page may have some information that may be useful to you.

Comment: To add to the answer , sometimes different Forex Vendors have different rates so some sort of user input for the exchange may be useful. But this will also depend on your client.